# StreamReader Could not find file (Because it is not being created)

Tags: c#, file, streamreader, streamwriter

I am trying to create a file for the further write to and read from.

I use Directory.CreateDirectory and File.Create but neither path nor file are being created.

On the Page which part I show here below I check if File exists, and if not, I create a File. On Second Page (that I dont show here) I add new lines to the file using StreamWrite. When saved, first Page comes to focus again and lists the content of the File(only one row in this study).

Here is my code for the part in question:

```
public async Task ReadFileAsync()
    {


        string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\Users\...\DataBase\");
        Task.Run(async() => Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName));
        Task.Run(async() => File.Create(directoryName + "ProductsDatabase.txt"));

        //code for reading from file
        string path = (directoryName + "ProductsDatabase.txt");

        using (StreamReader ProductsDatabaseRead = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(path)))
        {
            ProductOneTextBlock.Text = ProductsDatabaseRead.ReadLine();

        }
        if (ProductOneTextBlock.Text == "")
            {
            ProductOneTextBlock.Text = "Nothing to show";
            }
    }
```

The file and folder are not being created.

I don't get any error.

I tried also different folders on the drive in case if there was READ ONLY folder in solution folder. No difference.

Anyone could help? 
(I found many threads about this problem but here I cannot resolve it with none of the solutions.

Physical file is not being created.

When I attempt to write to it (from another page) I get error that the file could not be found(because it is not there indeed).

It seems that program loses itself somewhere between

```
Task.Run(async() => Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName));
        Task.Run(async() => File.Create(directoryName + "ProductsDatabase.txt"));
```

and:

```
using (StreamReader ProductsDatabaseRead = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(path)))
        {
            ProductOneTextBlock.Text = ProductsDatabaseRead.ReadLine();

        }
```

, as TextBlock is not being updated even if ProductsDatabaseRead is null.

If I put

```
ProductOneTextBlock.Text = "Nothing to show";
```

a the begining of the method, TextBlock gets updated.

SO, why the

```
using (StreamReader ProductsDatabaseRead = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(path)))
```

does not work?

Comment: Which error? Is "\...\" path part real or do you obfuscate "\patri\source\" for us?

Comment: no, I just hide the real path. error says: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Users\...\repos\DietMate\ProductsDatabase.txt'.' . It says so because the file in deed has not been created by the Task.Run

Comment: Why are you doing Task.Run?

Comment: because I get different error if not using it: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread.  Consider wrapping this method in Task.Run.'

Comment: Don't check `.Exists()`. This is one of those ugly cases where you're better off using exceptions :( ... just create the file using a mechanism that allows `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`, and handle the exception if it fails.

Comment: If you use Task.Run like that there is no guarantee that the directory or file will be created before you try to open the file.

Comment: I heard that there is no need for it. Anyway, deleted Exists and still getting same error about file not being found. (It is not being created)

Comment: but it doesnt let me CreateDirectory or File.Create without Task.Run

Comment: Don't use `Task.Run` for only those operations, wrap a complete `ReadFile` method call into `Task.Run` if you are using it in UI thread.

Comment: Are these the correct paths in your code? From what you've posted, you're trying to create a file in `repos\DietMate\DataBase\ `, but trying to read the file from `repos\DietMate\ `

Comment: YEs, there I had path wrong but I corrected it. Anyway, StreamReader does not give me errors now but somehow the file is not created physically.

Comment: @paddy as I mentioned, create a new question. The file you created can't be written to while you're having it opened for reading. But anyway -> start a new question, otherwise your current question will be downvoted and probably ignored <-

Comment: ok. thanks for advise, I delete the question and create a new one

Answer (score 4):

You're not waiting for `Task.Run` to complete. Your directory creation, file creation and attempt to open a "as you think newly created file" are out of order. That's why you're probably not able to open a file (it still does not exist at this point).

[`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a task that will be completed when the work is done. You need to wait for completion.

Comment: any way to force Task.Run to complete?

Comment: or maybe I should do async operation?

Comment: @paddy if you can make your whole function `async` then your actions should be like: 1) `await Task.Run(async() => await CreateDirAsync());` 2) `await Task.Run(async() => await CreateFileAsync());` 3) open a file.

Comment: @paddy if your whole  function can not be refactored to being `async` then you can block on every call by adding `.Wait()` like `Task.Run(() => Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName)).Wait()` but please note that it is considered bad practice =)

Comment: hold on.  I may be wrong. There is no error anymore but in the folder physically the file is not being saved. whats wrong?

Comment: @paddy there's really not enough info. Technically your code should create an empty file of 0 bytes length and then open it for reading. I don't know why you  are doing it and what you expect.

Comment: @paddy Also "the file is not being saved" is another question, so you'd better start a new one with another title, another code snippet that has no errors so people can read it and give you suggestions.

Comment: OK. Sorry. This operation is on First Page. It should return all data from file(if exists). Data is being added on second page, and then again first page gets focus to return all data with StreamReader

Answer (score 1):

```
public void ReadFile()
{
    string folderPath = @"C:\Users\patri\source\repos\DietMate\";
    string fileName = "ProductsDatabase.txt";
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);

    //insert code to check whether file exists.
    // use Exists()    
    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
        File.Create(fullPath);
    }

    //if yes, follow with code below
    //insert code for reading from file
    using (StreamReader ProductsDatabaseRead = new StreamReader(fullPath))
    {
        ProductTest.Text = ProductsDatabaseRead.ReadLine();
    }
}
```